# Moleculer JS "Redis-pub client is disconnected" every 10 minutes

Tags: redis, ioredis, moleculer

my application (Node.js) is using moleculer for microservices and redis as transporter. However, I find that the application will have this log `Redis-pub client is disconnected` every 10 minutes, then reconnect with the log `Redis-pub client is connected` after a few seconds. This is a problem because if a client send a moleculer action during this time, it will fail.

Any idea what is causing this? Let me know if more information is needed.

Comment: Where is running Redis server? Locally or a cloud redis instance?

Comment: Running on azure redis

Answer (score 0):

> Azure Cache for Redis currently has a 10-minute idle timeout for connections, so the idle timeout setting in your client application should be less than 10 minutes. Most common client libraries have a configuration setting that allows client libraries to send Redis PING commands to a Redis server automatically and periodically. However, when using client libraries without this type of setting, customer applications themselves are responsible for keeping the connection alive.

More info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-cache-for-redis/cache-best-practices-connection#idle-timeout